# Academic / formal word meaning opposite of entrenched / set in stone

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I want to find a way to convey the meaning of 'not being entrenched' and at the same time maintaining a formal / academic tone. The sentence I'm working with is:

> The market share leader board is becoming incrementally _________.

For context: There is reshuffling of ranks at all segments of the leader board now (whereas in the past it was very static/entrenched).

My early attempts included (and reasons why rejected):

- 'fluid' (seems too modernist)
- 'dynamic' (while the opposite of static, seems too abstract here)
- 'less entrenched' (unwieldy. I'm not 100% happy with using entrenched
  to describe a leader board)

### Question

What is an academic word that can convey that the leader board is 'less set in stone'? If there is no one magic word, a phrase would likely suffice.

Comment: Flexible, maybe?

Comment: If "Flexible" sounds too common, go with Unsclerotic.

Comment: **Displaced** (or perhaps **adjustable**)?

Comment: Changeable, variable,... but your "dynamic" is the most "academic" synonym already IMO.

Comment: [**Mutable**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mutable)?

Comment: In "dynamic equilibrium"

Comment: Is **untethered** fancy enough?

Comment: The leader board isn't doing *anything*. It is a *bin* governed by a rule that establishes it's members. So you need to take the focus off the leader board and put it on the components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A leader board reflects changes in the rankings (by whatever means) of its underlying members, competitors, or components.  Thus a good word would be

*volatile*

Subject to rapid and possibly unexpected change.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/volatile

Answer (score 2):

How about **shifting**? From M-W:

> **[shift](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shifting#other-words)**: to go through a change

Your example, slightly edited:

> The market-share leaderboard is incrementally **shifting**.

The combination of *incrementally* and *shifting* conveys the impression that previously the leaderboard was not shifting, i.e., that the leaderboard was static or "entrenched".

Answer (score 1):

A word that seems to be well suited to this is [**adaptable**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adaptable):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> : capable of being or becoming [adapted](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adapted)
>
> // an *adaptable* tool that combines a screwdriver, a corkscrew, and pliers
> // an activities director who's *adaptable* to any kind of situation

Unlike other synonyms, and in the context of the question, it has a specific sense of being able to "adapt to the times," which connotes a conscious effort towards positive change rather than just a general passive nature of being driven or manipulated by external forces.

Used in the example sentence:

> The market share leader board is becoming incrementally *adaptable*.

Answer (score 0):

Both **forward-looking** and **progressive** mean and encapsulate the opposite of *entrenched*:

> *forward-looking* [adjective]
>
> looking at the future in a positive way and happy to try new ideas and
> methods
>
> *a forward-looking policy/strategy/plan*

[[Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/forward-looking)]

> *forward-looking* [adjective]
>
> favouring innovation and development; progressive.
>
> *a forward-looking company*

[[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/forward-looking)]

....................

> *progressive* ...
>
> 1b: making use of or interested in new ideas, findings, or
> opportunities

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/progressive)]

Answer (score 0):

As is often the case, the poster has fallen into a trap of his own making. If you dispense with the superfluous “incrementally”, you can say something that approximates more to English, such as:

> The market share leader board is **changing more and more**.

However I dispute the idea that “leader board” is in any way academic or formal. To rework into formal English, while retaining the simplicity, I would write something like:

> The companies with the greatest market share are changing more and more.

But to include a single word, so that the charge of not answering the question doesn‘t hold, I offer [**inchoate**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inchoate). It has the advantage that few people will understand it.

Comment: Off the mark by a light year!

Comment: @Stockfish — Light year or not, I find your comment obscure. Or is it a play on words?

Comment: Light year has more to do with distance than time!